# Label references for associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, namespaces, integration-testing, fixtures

Rails provides label references for associations in fixtures like this:

```
### in pirates.yml

  reginald:
    name: Reginald the Pirate
    monkey: george

### in monkeys.yml

  george:
    name: George the Monkey
    pirate: reginald
```

This works great for not-namedspaced models, but I'm using namespaces, and so Rails gets confused, and want to insert the labels instead of the label references.

Any workaround or fix known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fixtures.identify` seems to be the only solution, not really beautiful but better than ids.

```
### in pirates.yml

  reginald:
    name: Reginald the Pirate
    monkey_id: <%= Fixtures.identify(:george) %>


### in monkeys.yml

  george:
    name: George the Monkey
    pirate_id: <%= Fixtures.identify(:reginald) %>
```

Comment: I had to change my file extension from `.yml` to `.yml.erb` to use embedded ruby like this (h/t https://stackoverflow.com/a/50619285/328817)