# Rails tests error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am a rails newb following tutorial from Agile Rails Web Development with rails 5.1. I am using rails 5.2

I created users with:

```
rails g scaffold User name:string password:digest
rails db:migrate


class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

All user tests fail with:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::FixtureSet::RenderContext::BCrypt
test/fixtures/users.yml:5:in `get_binding'
```

This is the fixtures file:

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  name: dave
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('secret') %>

two:
  name: susannah
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('secret') %>
```

Link to github: https://github.com/marko-avlijas/depot

I have no idea how to debug this and googling the error doesn't give me anything.

If I put `require 'bcrypt'` in test_helper I get:

`require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt (LoadError)

bo-oz suggested I paste the BCrypt::Password.create('secret') in console and use that in fixtures. But even that doesn't work. Through web interface I can create new user and server output indicates no errors, but in console I get this:

```
>> BCrypt::Password.create('secret')
NameError: uninitialized constant BCrypt
        from (irb):1
>> require 'bcrypt'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt
        from (irb):2
```

Comment: Do you have the `bcrypt` in your Gemfile? By default Rails will add the gem but in a comment so it won't be installed to your `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Yes and bundle has installed it.

Comment: I have bot used it but maybe try to specify the `cost` option - > `password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('secret, cost: 4') %>`

Comment: @radoAngelov - doesn't work

Comment: If it doesnt work in console, the problem is probablt that BCrypt doesnt get loaded. My first step would be focus on getting this to work in console. If it does, it will probably work in your fixtures as well.

Comment: @bo-oz -  but what can I do? It works in the app what's bizzare.

Comment: It's not in $LOAD_PATH in console

Comment: Dont know how to configure that, but it’s for sure part of the problem. I would suggest moving to Devise gem for authentication... a lot better idea than writing such a thing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `Bcrypt` gem is not installed. Although ti is not commented under `Gemfile`. Try running `bundle install` again and then run the tests.

Comment: It's not that, running bundle does not fix it.

Comment: maybe  `require 'bcrypt'` at the top of your test_helper.rb?

Comment: @bo-oz - thanks that gives me an error though. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why don't you just run `rails c`, paste the command for BCrypt, and use that output to manually assign a string to the password_digest attribute in your fixture.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a look at your repo. All your fixture files are with extension `.yml`. In `/fixtures/users.yml` you have embedded ruby so maybe change the filename to `fixtures/users.yml.erb`.

Also my comment above is quite wrong it should be `password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('secret', cost: 4) %>`. Use this only for testing since limiting the stretches to a number less than 10 will increase the performance of your test suite dramatically.

After downloading the your project and ran `rails console`

```
BCrypt::Password.create('testpassword', cost: 5)
=> "$2a$05$6PI2dUgqbb2LDSxEq2G.reINN9vyVRarFl7NAySQMdArJqqYy0/D."
```

If you still experience the same problem consider requiring the gem into your `test_helper.rb` and find out if you load it or not.

Comment: If I put `require 'bcrypt'` in test_helper then I get `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt (LoadError)`. Changing the fixture from `user.yml` to `user.yml.erb` changes the error message to `NoMethodError: undefined method 'users' for #<UsersControllerTest`. That means fixture is not recognized.

Comment: The fixture has to be "loaded" first. Can you post the code where you do it.

Comment: I am not sure what code you mean. I don't understand how rails tests load code and fixtures, it's magic. All I know is tests got generated with generate scaffold command.

Comment: Rspec has a config called `fixture_path` where you pass the path to your fixtures but in your case I think you don't need it.

When I am working with fixtures I usually define a helper method
`def load_fixture(file)`
  `File.read("spec/fixtures/#{file}")`
`end`

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit the last comment but the 5 minutes limit expired...

I was proposing there to try something like `user = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'users.yml')).with_indifferent_access` and to check what is happening. But these suggestions are only "shots in the dark", I am just trying to give you more options to try with :)

Comment: Thanks. I am using minitest. I am googling to see how rails loads fixtures, but it's automatic. I see a line in test_helper `fixtures :all
`. But it must end with `.yml`. Problem is that bcrypt isn't recognized in test or in console. Can't be required an isn't included. But it is bundle installed.